# How to use alasql in angular js controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alasql

I am using alasql in my angular js web app.

I have included

```
script(type='text/javascript',src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.2/alasql.min.js')
```

in my jade.

In my client side, in my module.js, I have included

```
angular.module('alasql.core', ['ui.router','restangular','alasql']);
```

And in my controller, I have injected the alasql.

```
angular.module('alasql.core')
    .controller('alasql.core.controller', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$window','alasql',

        function($rootScope, $scope, $window,alasql) {

            function _init() {
                console.log("Inside Home Controller");
                var years = [
                    { yearid: 2012 }, { yearid: 2013 },
                    { yearid: 2014 }, { yearid: 2015 },
                    { yearid: 2016 },
                ];

                var res = alasql.queryArray('SELECT * FROM ? AS years ' +
                    'WHERE yearid > ?', [years, 2014]);

                console.log("Array res");
                console.log(res);
            }

            _init();

            $('.ui.dropdown')
                .dropdown();
            $('.ui.accordion')
                .accordion();
        }
    ]);
```

I am getting the below error

It says module err. And if I remove the 'alasql' injection , there is no error. But alasql.queryArray function remains undefined.

What is the correct procedure to inject alasql to my angular js controller?
Please let me know.

Regards,
Sabarisri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace

```
alasql.queryArray('SELECT * FROM ? AS years ' +
                'WHERE yearid > ?', [years, 2014]);
```

with

```
alasql('SELECT * FROM ? AS years ' +
                'WHERE yearid > ?', [years, 2014]);
```